# I dont know why TinyMCE is disabled in Firefox(14.0.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, tinymce

(Rails app) - In a webpage, I am using multiple forms. Inside each form I have a tinyMCE editor with different id's. But, when it renders, I can see that the TinyMCE editor in the second form is disbaled and when I perform edit action on the form, the TinyMCE content is just flashing inside the TinyMCE and it goes. Then the TinyMCE gets disbaled.

I have integrated the TinyMCE as a plugin and I have initialized it properly. I think the version is 3.4.5.

What could be the issue? Thanks for the help in adv. :)-

Comment: is the textarea for the second editor visible when you try to init the editor?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean....

Comment: each tinymce editor has a source html element (a textarea for example) for which the editor gets initialized. is this html element visible when to try to init the editor?

Comment: Yes, I could see the text area and it is not disabled at all..

Comment: ok, then the root of evil is somewhere else

Comment: In the same(second) form other text areas are enabled with TinyMCE which are working fine. Also in the first form I have a textraea which is also working fine with TinyMCE. The thing is that the init spec for the textarea in 1st form and 2nd form is only in the option 'editor_selector'. The issue is happening with Firefox only. Chrome 23.0.1 is working fine.

Comment: Is there any problem in having two initializations in the same page?

Comment: no, as long as your source html elements do have a unique id